# Download link for AMD beta drivers not working

Tags: drivers, amd-radeon, gaming, display-driver, amd-graphics-card

Per [this question](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1860011-Crashes-when-trying-to-changing-clothes-first-time-Forums) Far Cry 5 is crashing when changing clothes for the first. Per the thread it is recommended to download and install some AMD beta drivers from [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx), however the download link for both the 32-bit and 64-bit beta drivers seems broken.

There appears to be another download link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvCiU1sG1KU), however I am a little weary of installing from this source.

Question 1: Is there another official link where I can get these drivers, or some way to fix the existing broken link? None of the suggestions on the download page seemed to be the cause.

Question 2: Failing Question 1, does anybody have the original executable they could run a SHA-256 hash on and compare it to the one from the link on the youtube page above and post the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't said what OS or GPU you have, the best anyone can do is point you at the AMD downloads page, so you can navigate it yourself.

https://support.amd.com/en-us/download

I presume you have a legacy card - most of the relevant posts from your link are of the legacy HD6xxx series.
You'll note AMD no longer list that in the 'download chooser' section, but you can find drivers in the Latest Drivers list lower down.

Your choices on a legacy card will be 15.7.1 or 16.2.1 beta
Try both.
Use the clean install feature in the installer's advanced option & don't install the full suite, just the drivers & control panel.

Btw, the error message generated on the AMD site is a new addition. For some reason it will not allow you to link from another domain directly to that page & get the files. I've been sending people to that 15.11.1 beta page for years & now it's blocked.

Comment: Nevermind. I see it now. Let me try. Thanks.

Comment: Having trouble fully installing this driver, but I suppose the question was where to find them, so I'll mark this correct.